# TypeError: can't convert Class into String

Tags: ruby

A test gaves me that error on this method,

```
def test_create
 get :new    
 assert_template 'admin/supplier/new'
 assert_difference(Supplier, :count) do
   post :create, :supplier => {:name => 'Juan', :province => 'provincia'}
   assert_response :redirect
   assert_redirected_to :action => 'index'      
 end
 assert_equal 'was succesfully created.', flash[:notice]
end
```

exactly the error is on

```
assert_difference(Supplier, :count) do
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't using `assert_difference` correctly. Try

```
assert_difference 'Supplier.count' do
```

More examples are in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions.html)